# Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden - User) Azure Pipeline

Tags: nuget

```
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\NuGet.targets(128,5): 
 error :   
   Response status code does not indicate success: 403 
     (Forbidden - User '2016d1a0-0d43-42b0-8a96-7f6a9bxxxxxx' lacks permission to complete this action. You need to have 'ReadPackages'. 
     (DevOps Activity ID: ADACCF88-4190-491C-B690-E3330E3xxxxx)). 
   [D:\a\1\s\Notifications.Functions\Notifications.Application.csproj]
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:08.96


##[error]Error: The process 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: **Solved:** projectname / Settings / Pipeline Settings.

**Disable:**
Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines
Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines
Publish metadata from pipelines (preview)

Answer (score 8):

This error message appears if the build service doesn't have permission to access your Azure Artifacts feed. To fix this:

1. Go to your Azure Artifacts page.
2. Select the **Feed Settings** button, then select the **Permissions** tab.
3. Select **Add users/groups**.
4. In the **User/Group** box, type `[ProjectName] Build Service` (where `[ProjectName]` is the name of the Azure DevOps project containing the pipeline you're trying to push from) and select the corresponding group that appears in the dropdown.
5. Set the **Role** to **Contributor**. Then select **Save**.

Now when you run the pipeline, it will be able to push nuget packages to the Azure Artifacts feed without issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check feed have "Contributor" permission to "Build Service", usually it is "Collaborator" if it was already added by Azure.